# Save each javascript value to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I success to display with javascript each input value after clicking on send button. I have a mysql table in which I want to save all the values sent after clicking in the second button (*Save all values to database*).

I'm stuck in how to save them in the database. I'm very happy to be helped acheiving this.

I wish to use jquery and ajax to grab and pass the variable to php and save them into the database. My framework is codeigniter.

My issue is I ignore how to grab them and pass them to php using jquery and ajax.

Thanks

```
<input id='textMessage'/>
<button type='button' id='send-message'>
send
</button>


<div id='load-data'>

</div>
<br/>
<button type='button' id='save'>
Save all values to database
</button>

$('#send-message').click(function(){
sendTxtMessage($('#textMessage').val());
$('#textMessage').val('');
});


function sendTxtMessage(message){
var str = '<span>';
str+='<br/>'+message ;
str+='</span>';
$('#load-data').append(str);
}
```

My fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6L1epk9g/

Comment: If you are using codeignitor you would typically save to the database using PHP.

Comment: yes I can use php to save but my issue is I ignore how to save all the displayed values at one go after clicking on the save to database button.

Comment: you need a <form> to submit the data-: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0):

For saving all the values in MySql database, at first you have to create tables in mysql. Second you have to make a connection to your mysql database using your userid and password for the database. Third you have to pass the values (getting the values) through api to server side for storing in database. You can use jQuery get/post method for the purpose. Check this link https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: thanks for your response. To be clear I know all the stuff about connection to database with php. My issue is: if you look at my fiddle, each time we send the value  it's shown down in a list format. Now I want to grab the list of variable using jquey and ajax to pass them to php and there I will save into database

Comment: Hi,I think you are storing all the message in the variable "str".All the new messages you are appending to the same variable.So can you specify what do you mean by "I want to grab the list of variable"?And which format you want to send the data?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for willing to help me. I happen to find out the way to solve my issue.
I just added the rest of the codes

First I need to grab the variable 'str' and pass it to the ajax.

*Knowing that the input will receive only number.*

```
$('#save').click(function(){
var val=[];
 //the div that receive str variable (load-data)
$('#load-data').each(function(){
val.push($(this).text());
});   
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?=base_url('admin/SaveData')?>",
data: {val:val},
success:function(data){

},

});       
});
```

save to database with php

```
 public function SaveData()
{
$val =$this->input->post('val');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); ++$i ) {

$value = $val[$i];
$save= array(
'service' =>$value
);
$this->model->SaveData($save);
```

}